# Unable to perform transaction: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: Not showing any clear message

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, react, solidity-0.8.x

**Error display on Etherscan**

*Fail with error 'ERC721: transfer from incorrect owner'*

I used the transaction hash and found the above error

**Error while trying to sell nft**

[image]

**Data of the NFT, this function is trying to buy**
[image]

**Solidity function for buying NFT**

```
function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint256 price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
        require(
            msg.value == price,
            "Insuffient ether sent for the NFT purchase"
        );
        address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;

        idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
        idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
        _itemsSold.increment();

        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

        approve(address(this), tokenId);

        payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

**JS Function to buy NFT** Sending static data for testing

```
let {price, tokenId} = await contractMethods
      .getLatesIdToListedToken()
      .call((err, res) => {
        console.log('PRICE RES: ', res);
      });
    let data = contractMethods.executeSale(tokenId).encodeABI();
    let txnObj;
    try {
      txnObj = {
        to: MarketplaceAddress,
        value: price,
        gas: 10000000,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
        data: data,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error :', err);
    }
    try {
      const signTxn = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
        txnObj,
        privateKey,
        (error, response) => {
          console.log('Error Signing: ', error);
        },
      );
      try {
        signTxn
          .then(signedTxn => {
            const brodcastTxn = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
              signedTxn.rawTransaction,
              (error, txnHash) => {},
            );
            brodcastTxn.on('error', error => {
              console.log('error :', error);
            });
            brodcastTxn.on('confirmation', receipt => {
              console.log('confirmation :', receipt);
            });
            brodcastTxn.on('receipt', receipt => {
              console.log('Receipt :', receipt);
            });
            brodcastTxn.on('sent', sent => {
              console.log('sent Receiver:', sent);
            });
            brodcastTxn.on('sending', sending => {
              console.log('sending Receiver:', sending);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error Signing Transaction :', error);
          });
      } catch (errors) {
        console.log('ERROR : ', errors);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error', err);
    }
```